# Can I edit the datasource programatically with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that pulls data via ajax into the datasource.

Once that data is pulled, I want to modify a bunch at once through JS.  I have tried modifying the datasource directly via something like:

```
gridDataSource._data[j].SomeProperty = 'true;
```

But that does not reflect in the grid itself.  Is there any way to do that?  I would also prefer the grid gets marked dirty so I could use the update command to send the data back to the server.  Is this possible?  Please let me know if I need to clear anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the set method - like this:

```
var data = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
data[i].set("SomeProperty", true);
```

Comment: This is great!  Any way to mark the affected cells as dirty (little trangle)?

Comment: I recall seeing some discussion about this somewhere - I believe Teleriks response was no (automatically), but you can accomplish it by adding a css class to the cell - though, I believe it gets complicated identifying the right elements, etc...  I would look around for an example and open a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

After you modify the datasource, you need to refresh.

```
$('#myGrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```